# Removing overlaps from buffered line features in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, buffer, overlay, borders

I know this question has been asked already but it seems that there is still no answer to it:

My buffered streets shapefiles (which consists of many different segments/objects) overlay where the different line objecs cross.

[image]

Is it somehow possible to remove these overlaying regions automatically (so without Topology-Rules, this has to be done manually) and to create a new single border of the buffers where the buffers meet.
The ArcGIS 'Business Analyst toolbox' offers a tool called 'Remove Overlap' which does something like that, but unfortunately I don't have this extension.

Comment: I suppose Arc has some option to dissolve your buffers.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. What do you want to do where they overlap?

Comment: Yes in ArcGIS you can choose the option 'dissolve buffers' but when I do this I get a singplepart feature which consists of only one object. So I want to preserve the single street ID in the buffer result. Also I want to create a new border, something like a thiessen polygon.

Comment: Why not 'Remove Overlap (multiple) (Analysis)' from the Overlay toolset? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/remove-overlap-multiple.htm

Comment: Hey thanks for your answers! But unfortunately the remove overlap (multiple) tool also doesn't work, because it only removes overlaps from multiple input layers. My overlaps are within one layer, which consists of thousands of street objects.